# How to enable revisioning for user photo (user/profile field)?

Tags: media, files, nodes

I want to moderate pictures, uploaded as user avatars. So, I need:

1. History for user field “Photo” to see all previous photoes.
2. UI for accepting or declining new photo.

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [User Revision module](http://drupal.org/project/user_revision) would probably be your best bet

> Add revision support to users and fields like there is for nodes.
>
> For the moment all field from {users} have revisions, except for password

The picture property is contained in the `users` table so this module should do exactly what you're looking for.

The issue of a UI for accepting or declining a photo should go in another question otherwise this one will become too localised.

Comment: Thanks, @Clive! Yes, _User Revision_ works for fields in User entity. Unfortunately it doesn't work for Profile2 fields.

Comment: Ah yeah, doesn't look like profile2 implements revisioning for its entity type. Sounds like a good feature request though :)

Comment: user revision can also mess up the registration process. make sure you **uninstall** before removing it.